# Nested struct in Cython

Tags: python, cython, python-c-extension

I'm hoping to get some help declaring and using a nested struct type with Cython. In the sqlite3.h header file, there is this:

```
struct sqlite3_index_info {
  int nConstraint;           /* Number of entries in aConstraint */

  struct sqlite3_index_constraint {
     int iColumn;              /* Column on left-hand side of constraint */
     unsigned char op;         /* Constraint operator */
     unsigned char usable;     /* True if this constraint is usable */
     int iTermOffset;          /* Used internally - xBestIndex should ignore */
  } *aConstraint;            /* Table of WHERE clause constraints */
  ... more members ...
}
```

That is the only place `sqlite3_index_constraint` is declared.

In an example C library provided by the author of SQLite, these structs are used:

```
 const struct sqlite3_index_constraint *pConstraint;
 pConstraint = pIdxInfo->aConstraint;
```

I've tried to declare the "sqlite3_index_constraint" separately, so I have:

```
const struct sqlite3_index_constraint *pConstraint; 
pConstraint = pIdxInfo->aConstraint;
```

In my code I try to `cdef sqlite3_index_constraint *pConstraint` and it cythonizes, but fails to compile with:

```
error: unknown type name ‘sqlite3_index_constraint’
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'd expect it would work if you `cdef`ed `sqlite3_index_constraint` as a normal non-nested struct in Cython (the Cython declaration often doesn't have to match the C one exactly for it to work). Other than that, you might need to post a bit more of your Cython code for anyone to comment.